# Reset string after loop iteration php

Tags: php, sql

I need to do a sql query dynamically. My code is simple to understand: my function receives an array and a string containing the query, and I'll iterate through the array to use the key values in the "where" part of my query. Here's a part of the code:

```
function graficoTeste ($array, $sql) {
    $conn = connect();

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $sql .= "'". $key. "'";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        if(!$result)
            echo $conn->error;

        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $array[$key] = $row["count_est"];
        }
    }
```

The problem is:
I need that my query adds the $key value each time the foreach iterates, but I am concatenating the string $sql (which contains the actual query) with $key, which results in:

```
SELECT COUNT(Estudante) AS count_est FROM `2016-1` WHERE municipio='Jatai'
SELECT COUNT(Estudante) AS count_est FROM `2016-1` WHERE municipio='Jatai''Goiânia'
SELECT COUNT(Estudante) AS count_est FROM `2016-1` WHERE municipio='Jatai''Goiânia''Goiás'
SELECT COUNT(Estudante) AS count_est FROM `2016-1` WHERE municipio='Jatai''Goiânia''Goiás''Catalão'
```

And I need it to be:

```
SELECT COUNT(Estudante) AS count_est FROM '2016-1' WHERE municipio='Jatai'
SELECT COUNT(Estudante) AS count_est FROM `2016-1` WHERE municipio='Goiânia'
SELECT COUNT(Estudante) AS count_est FROM `2016-1` WHERE municipio='Goiás'
SELECT COUNT(Estudante) AS count_est FROM `2016-1` WHERE municipio='Catalão'
```

Is there any way to revert the $sql string to its default (without the $key at the end) for every time the loop iterates?

Thank you very much 
(Sorry for my bad english and for the portuguese code, hahah).

Comment: What a wonderful example to illustrate why you should *always* use parameters instead of munging values in query strings.

Comment: But if this ^ is too hard for you, then `$result = $conn->query($sql . "'". $key. "'");`

Comment: Where are you defining the `$sql` variable?  If you want it to "reset" with each loop iteration then it sounds like it should be defined *in the loop*.  Or at the very least not modified by the loop.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yep. I just can't see a way to pass everything tomy function. I'll try a different approach. :/ Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @u_mulder It worked, thanks a lot. But I'm not happy with this code, I'll try to change it and pass everything as parameters. But thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

To run the same SQL statement with varying WHERE clauses simply use a placeholder in the statement, prepare the statement, and run it in a loop with your key/value pairs. The prepared statement is reused each time it is run.

Your statement will look like this:

`SELECT COUNT(Estudante) AS count_est FROM '2016-1' WHERE municipio = ?`

Your code will roughly have this setup:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(Estudante) AS count_est FROM '2016-1' WHERE municipio = ?";
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $stmt->execute(array($key));
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        print_r($row);
    }
}
```

As a siding effect re-using a prepared statement speeds up operation as the database does not have to parse the SQL and prepare an execution plan for each and every call, but just once. The execution time saved may be considerable.

See also:
[Prepared statements and stored procedures at php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

But, depending on the data in your database, it may be much more efficient to use one query

`SELECT COUNT(Estudante) AS count_est, municipio  FROM '2016-1' group by municipio`

and look up the city name in your PHP array when you retrieve the result set from the database - probably much less server load and execution time compared to running single queries in a loop.

Edit 1: typo fixed, Edit 2: suggested GROUP BY statement